# iterm2で非選択時、コマンドライン行コピーを行うキーバインドを実装したいです。

Tags: macos, command-line, shell, iterm

iterm2のキーバインドでのcmd+Cが現状、文字選択時のみにクリップボードへのコピーを行う機能となっています。
VSCode等のエディタではcmd+Cにより、選択時は選択箇所を、非選択時にはカーソル行をコピーするような機能があると思います。

この機能をiterm2上でなおかつcmd+Cのキーで実装したいと考えております。
shellにfishを用いているのでfishにてコマンドライン行のコピーコマンドを作り、そのキーバインドをiterm2上で割り当ててみたところ、当然のごとく、選択時のコピー機能を失ってしまいました。

fishコマンドに選択箇所の読み取りコマンドのようなものがあれば実現可能と考えているのですが、割り当てるキーを変える以外に何か同様の機能を実装する手段はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterm2 python　APIにて実現できそうなので試してみます。
ありがとうございました。

<<<追記
python APIを用いた際、文字選択をする機能を用いることができ、コピー機能はコマンド実行により実行することで文字選択できたか否かで条件分岐をすることで実現しました。

以下のスクリプトをデーモンとして動かし、キーバインドしました。参考までに。
https://github.com/s0ran/copy_with_line

Comment: 解決したら解決した方法をぜひ回答として書いてほしいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。更新しましたので是非みてみてください。